# Is this usage of "or rather" correct? If so, what does it mean here?

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence.

> There is one striking similarity about the two cases: in both, the legal personality of
>   the EU (respectively as ECSC and EC) is invoked. The individual institutions lack
>   legal personality and this, it seems, has a serious implication. Lacking personality,
>   the Commission cannot enter into treaties under international law, so France v
>   Commission case suggests, **or rather**, it cannot be held responsible in its own right and thus
>   its behavior will inevitably be attributed to the EU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this usage of "or rather" is correct.

According to the [Cambridge Online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rather), this usage of "rather" fits into the definition given in B2.

> more accurately; more exactly:

Substituting the definition into the sentence gives us

> [...] the Commission cannot enter into treaties under international law [...], or more accurately, it cannot be held responsible in its own right and thus its behavior will inevitably be attributed to the EU.

"Or rather" as a phrase is used to correct oneself (see [Cambridge Grammar - Or Rather](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/rather)). In writing, this self-correction is usually rhetorical (done for effect), because the author could always go back and edit their sentence to remove the need for correction. The technique is often used to describe something in an easy to understand but not quite correct way, and then to present the more correct but more difficult version as a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down one sentence:

> Lacking personality, the Commission /
>
> cannot enter into treaties under international law, [as] *France v Commission* suggests, /
>
> or rather, /
>
> it cannot be held responsible in its own right and thus its behavior will inevitably be attributed to the EU.

The "so" in the second line, refers back to the previous statement.

The sentence says that a judicial ruling that the Commission cannot enter into treaties is better stated as – the Commission itself cannot be held responsible.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Comment: You don't seem to answer the actual question.